# git (GitHub) times out on EC2 server that previously could connect

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2

Recently, a server stopped being able to connect to git repositories, hosted by GitHub.  This occurred on a server that has been successfully connecting to GitHub for 2+ years, cloning multiple repos per day.  Also, no changes were made in the GitHub account at all, and definitely no security settings.

The following is the output we get:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-123:~/test$ git clone https://github.com/OrganizationName/XYZ.git
Cloning into 'XYZ'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/OrganizationName/XYZ.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

This is a wide-ranging connection issue, as we are unable to ping GitHub:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-221:~/test$ ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.253.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
```

The above ping will hang for pretty much as long as you will let it.  Yet, we are able to ping successfully any other host we have tried:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-123:~/test$ ping stackoverflow.com
PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.193.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=0.748 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=0.802 ms
```

What we have tried so far:

1. We verified all GitHub credentials and that the account is in good standing.
2. The security group attached to the EC2 instance allows all outbound traffic.
3. We are able to connect to git and github via other servers in the same VPC.
4. We have updated all packages and updated Ubuntu (v16.04)
5. We are able to clone, pull, and push repositories on local machines and other EC2 servers.
6. We attached a different elastic IP, and the problem still persisted
7. We cloned the server by creating an AMI and spinning up a copy of the server.  The copy had the same issue.

It seems that the problem is likely with the server, not the service (we have contacted GitHub support just in case, but we haven't heard back yet).  It doesn't seem to be an IP block, and it is unclear what changed.  I can verify that nothing has been changed since only one person (myself) has access to both the server and GitHub account.

What have we not thought of or what could have changed to cause this block?  Thanks.

Comment: looks more of the AWS issue, then outside problem. I would suggest you check with AWS support for a prompt response.

Comment: That's a good thought- we hadn't contacted AWS yet, but we opened a ticket and will post a resolution if this is simply an AWS issue.

Comment: Is this issue still happening ?

Comment: Could also try git clone  ssh:// or git://